# Is the sentence “He wanted that she woke him up at 8 o'clock” correctly constructed?

Tags: sentence-structure

I am really confused about this sentence construction. I wanted to know which is better. I could think about these structures, but I don't know which of them are correct.

1. He wanted that she woke him up at 8 o'clock.
2. He wanted her to woke him up at 8 o'clock.
3. He wanted her to wake him up at 8 o'clock.
4. He wanted to be awaken by her at 8 o'clock.

I did a little research and I found that a sentence constructed as 3 (He wanted her to wake him up at 8 o'clock) would be better than 1 (He wanted that she woke him up at 8 o'clock), but I didn't understand why. Is 1 wrong? Do 1 and 3 have the same meaning?

Comment: AFAIK, *want* doesn't license a *that-clause* as a complement.

Answer (score 1):

I would say for #1

> He wanted that she **wake** him up at 8 o'clock.

though your original sentence

> He wanted that she **woke** him up at 8 o'clock.

would be understood to mean the same.

Your #3 sentence is best and more natural

> He wanted her to wake him up at 8 o'clock.
>
> He wanted *(something in the past)*
>   her
>   to wake *(something in the future, from that point in the past)*
>   him
>   up at 8 o'clock.

Your #2 sentence

> He wanted her to woke him up at 8 o'clock.

is incorrect.

Your #4 sentence should be either of

> He wanted to be awaken**ed** by her at 8 o'clock.
>   He wanted to be **awoken** by her at 8 o'clock.